# Create traffic light in SUMO and OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

How I can create **traffic** **light** in OMNeT++ and SUMO, i have to create the traffic light and configure in XML file from which file using veins example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OMNeT++ proxy modules for SUMO traffic lights are available since Veins 4.7.

If you have a network including a traffic light, you need to add the following lines to your omnetpp.ini file:

```
*.manager.trafficLightModuleType = "org.car2x.veins.nodes.TrafficLight"
*.manager.trafficLightModuleName = "trafficLight"
*.manager.trafficLightModuleDisplayString = default
*.manager.trafficLightFilter = "MYTRAFFICLIGHTID"
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.x = 0
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.y = 0
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.z = 3

*.trafficLight[*].applType = "YOURAPPLAYERTYPE"
*.trafficLight[*].logicType = "YORUTRAFFICLIGHTLOGIC"
```

The term `MYTRAFFICLIGHTID` needs to be replaced with the ID you're using in your SUMO network. If you have multiple traffic lights to control, you can list SUMO IDs separated by spaces.

A traffic light consists of an application (`YOURAPPLAYERTYPE`) and a logic (`YORUTRAFFICLIGHTLOGIC`). Both properties are mandatory and need to be specified in your omnetpp.ini.

In the current Veins master branch, the `YOURAPPLAYERTYPE` is an OMNeT++ module, that uses the `DemoBaseApplLayer` as a the base module.

```
class YOURAPPLAYERTYPE: public DemoBaseApplLayer {
....
}
```

The `YORUTRAFFICLIGHTLOGIC` is an OMNeT++ module, that uses the `TraCITrafficLightAbstractLogic` as a the base module.

```
class YORUTRAFFICLIGHTLOGIC: public TraCITrafficLightAbstractLogic{
....
}
```

Comment: How i can create traffic file xml in sumo first because i create in sumo traffic light and i didn't found where is modified

Comment: There is a tag called "tlLogic" - http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/PlainXML