# Traffic light state in OMNeT++ and Sumo

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm working on a project using Veins (v5.1) along with SUMO (v1.8) and OMNeT++ (v5.6.2) to simulate the communication between vehicles and traffic lights.

From my understanding, OMNeT++ doesn't actually recognize traffic lights but they might be implemented as RSUs to simulate the communication with the vehicle.

Using SUMO and netedit, I've made some nodes and a junction where the traffic light is located and I've prepared the xml file with the traffic light states. I suppose that this file is used to initialize the state of the traffic light. Is there any way to change the status of the traffic light at runtime during the simulation?

Besides the xml file, could I set the state of the traffic light using OMNet++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create traffic light in SUMO and OMNeT++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693016/create-traffic-light-in-sumo-and-omnet)

Comment: Partly yes, thank you! However, it's not clear to me where I should create the two new classes or what is necessary for those classes to contain. Sorry if this something self explanatory, I just started learning about these subjects. 
Is it also possible to modify the status of the traffic lights while the simulation is running?

Comment: Where to create: This is up to you. this does not change the way your logic works
Possible to change the traffic lights: Yes.

Comment: Is there a reading material on this that I might have missed?